# Java code for Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been practicing implementing a linked list from scratch. Can someone help review my code?

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    int num;

    public Node(int val) {
        num = val;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class LinkedList {

    Node head;

    public LinkedList(int val) {
        head = new Node(val);
    }

    public void append(int val) {
        Node tmpNode = head;
        while (tmpNode.next != null) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }
        tmpNode.next = new Node(val);
    }

    public void insert(int val) {
        Node currentNode = head;
        Node nextNode = head.next;

        if (currentNode.num > val) {
            Node tmpNode = head;
            head = new Node(val);
            head.next = tmpNode;
            return;
        }

        if (nextNode != null && nextNode.num > val) {
            currentNode.next = new Node(val);
            currentNode.next.next = nextNode;
            return;
        }

        while (nextNode != null && nextNode.num < val) {
            currentNode = nextNode;
            nextNode = nextNode.next;
        }

        currentNode.next = new Node(val);
        currentNode.next.next = nextNode;
    }

    public void delete(int val) {
        Node prevNode = null;
        Node currNode = head;

        if (head.num == val) {
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }

        while (currNode != null && currNode.num != val) {
            prevNode = currNode;
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }

        if (currNode == null) {
            System.out.println("A node with that value does not exist.");
        }
        else {
            prevNode.next = currNode.next;
        }

    }

    public void print() {
        Node tmpNode = head;
        while (tmpNode != null) {
            System.out.print(tmpNode.num + " -> ");
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(5);
        myList.append(7);
        myList.append(16);
        myList.insert(9);
        myList.insert(4);
        myList.insert(6);
        myList.insert(17);
        myList.delete(16);
        myList.delete(5);
        myList.delete(4);
        myList.delete(17);
        myList.delete(34);
        myList.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just realized my append function doesn't check if head is null at the beginning also. My current function would throw an NPE if it was null.

Answer (score 7):

1. Your implementation does not allow for an empty list.

   1. It's a bit odd to only have the constructor which takes a node value.
2. You should probably implement the `List` interface.
3. You should look into generics instead of hard-coding your list to only take `int`s.
4. It looks like from looking at `insert()` that you are trying to create an **ordered** linked list.  However, `append()` does not.  (If you really want to define an ordered linked list, you can still use generics, but you'll have to use types which are children of `Comparable`).
5. In `insert()` and `delete()` you have some `if`-conditions followed by a `while`-loop.  My guess is that they can be merged in a single `while`-loop.  I was lazy and haven't tried doing it, so it might not be true.

Answer (score 4):

What [@toto2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31361/26200) said plus

- I would change the `print` method. Override [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.
- Do not put `System.out.println` in an API class. You will be reusing your `LinkedList` class in future in GUI or Web app. Then unwanted SOPs will hamper your code.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly as already said:

- Mixing `insert()` with `append()`? Does it make sense? Choose one
- You do not accept an empty list.

Here is a turbo-fast example with `append()` accepting an empty list:

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    int num;
    public Node(int val) {
        num = val;
        next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {

    private Node head = null;

    public void append(int val) {
        Node lastNode = getLastNode();
        if (lastNode == null) {
            head = new Node(val);
        } else {
            lastNode.next = new Node(val);
        }
    }

    public void delete(int val) {
        if(head == null){
            return;
        }

        Node prevNode = null;
        Node currNode = head;
        while (currNode != null && currNode.num != val) {
            prevNode = currNode;
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        if(prevNode == null){
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        if (currNode == null) {
            System.out.println("A node with that value does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        prevNode.next = currNode.next;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("");
        if(head == null){
            System.out.print("EMPTY");
            return;
        }
        Node tmpNode = head;
        while (tmpNode != null) {
            System.out.print(tmpNode.num + " -> ");
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }
    }

    private Node getLastNode() {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Node tmpNode = head;
        while (tmpNode.next != null) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }
        return tmpNode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        myList.print();
        myList.append(35);
        myList.append(33);
        myList.print();
        myList.delete(33);
        myList.delete(35);
        myList.delete(35);
        myList.print();
    }
}
```

It's just an example, so you would like to implement the absolute minimum, but of course Generics, Comparable, `System.out.print` are still actual topics.